# onsaveInstancestate not saving int values

Tags: android, savestate

When i try rotating the screen it does not erase the data, but when I go from the activity and back the counter value goes back to 0.

I have set make the method for saving the data, but it still doesnt save. Why is this?

```
  package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button myButton;
private int Counter = 0;
private Button myButton2;
private TextView myTextView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int add = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("Count");
        add = savedInstanceState.getInt("Add");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Counter = ButtonCounter(Counter);
        }
    });
    myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
 SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    });

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Counter = AutoCounter(Counter, add);
            Display(Counter, myTextView);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }, 10);


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Count", Counter);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Add", add);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


public int ButtonCounter(int Counter) {
    Counter += 1;
    return Counter;
}

public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
    Counter += add;
    return Counter;
}

public void Display(int Counter, TextView myTextView) {
    String man = String.valueOf(Counter);
    myTextView.setText("$" + man);
}


}
```

Comment: What did you mean by "when I go from the activity"? When is this happening? When you hit the back button or when you open the second activity?

Comment: open second activity

Comment: You call finish() when you open the SecondActivity, so the saved instance state bundle is not saved. Also when you close the activity by hitting the back button the behavior is the same. The method onSaveInstanceState is mostly used for saving data on orientation change. If you want to save the counter, you may consider using SharedPreferences -
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html.

Answer (score 0):

My code runs like that...

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt("Count", Counter);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("Count"))
        {
            Counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("Count");
        }
    }
}
```

Difference is that i don't have final Bundle on create and i save it after super.onSave.. wich seems odd....